# Most sustainable roofing for short term equipment shelter

Tags: roofing, materials

A simple wood frame is going up over some infrastructure in a farm field (a device with a motor in a sealed weather-resistant stainless-steel box). This wood frame is meant to help protect against sun, rain and wind. What is the best siding for the environment and apx. 5yr functionality?

Some not so great options I considered: Woven plastic tarps seem like a short-sighted option, I hate those plastic bits flying around as they fall apart in a few years. Canvas tarp might be better but less weather resistant and will rot eventually anyway.

Now for the promising options: Wood boards are a more accessible option for me, easy for me to screw on plank shingles or broad sheets. Wood will rot but this structure is somewhat impermanent as you can see from the sketchy design, eventually something better will be setup, and I'd hope the wood would be ok for a few years and then rot and store carbon while it does. Metal is the most long-term option but not sure it's more environmentally friendly, and it's also less accessible for me. Maybe plywood with some environmentally friendly covering?

Here's a pic of what I'm assembling.

[image: pic of wood frame from angle]

[image: wood frame from side]

It's shabby but will be functional for this purpose, and it needs to be assembled during a relatively short visit in the field, quick and easy moving materials with a pickup truck. The more weatherproof the siding, the better - this needs to withstand heavy rain, heavy (1ft+) snow loads, zone 4 winters, heavy wind from one side (the other side has a forested windbreak). I'm just asking about **what siding is the most sustainable option, also considering replacement intervals and lifecycle impacts.**

Comment: I had first posted this on the sustainability SE but am moving it here for more construction expertise

Comment: For your case painted/stain exterior plywood probably the best.  Your main problem will be to anchor it to the ground well enough for the wind.

Comment: @crip659 thanks, noted. If not staining, would horizontal plank shingles last much longer than plywood?

Comment: corrugated metal siding.  you can probably get enough scrap from a commercial install given the small nature of your project.  the newer galvalum is like car panels that never rot out.  it is relatively light (compared to plywood) so easier to move.

Comment: If the device (pump being the usual one) is protected by a stainless steel casing, this all seems un-needed. Is the device exposed and only its motor protected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wooden shingle done right should last more than 5 years. Done right is not clapboards (which you are calling "horizontal plank shingles") - if you look around you'll find that those are used for siding, but not roofing.

Concrete or ceramic tiles will last longer, centuries or beyond for ceramics, unless subjected to things other than rain that break them. If you rebuild the structure before it collapses and breaks the tiles, you can re-use them.

The wood set in the dirt will rot away and cause you problems, though. You also need to tie the thing down so it does not get blown away.

Corrugated metal roofing is fairly normal in this sort of application and typically (depending on local market, of course) costs less.

If you want to work hard for high sustainability, thatch will work. It's very old-fangled and about as sustainable a roof as can be. Local expertise (and materials) may be hard to come by in many locations, though. Pretty sure you have to get the eaves up off the ground so it can dry, or you'll promote rot, which would require a change in design.

As for "storing carbon" - that's what the tree did when it made the wood. When the wood rots, carbon is released. The only way to **store** carbon from wood long term is to partially burn it - archaeologists find charcoal from fires thousands of years ago.

Answer (score 3):

It's like you're building an A-frame and each wall as a totally separate structure that doesn't know the other parts exist, finish them all and then ???? to join them.  Well, the ??? is going to fail in the weather conditions you're talking about.  That's not going to work.  There are plenty of drawings on the web, think doghouse.

As far as the best environmentally sustainable roof and wall covering, you just can't beat corrugated steel roofing.  Cut it into 12" x 12" square and throw it in the recycle bin.  Or the trash, even - almost every dump has an extraction stream that will yank right out ferrous metals.